# Finding how many edges a graphs has if $ab \equiv 1 \bmod p$

Tags: graph-theory, modular-arithmetic

> How many edges does a graph have if the vertices are corresponded to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (where $p$ is a prime number), where the vertices $a$ and $b$ are connected to one edge if and
> only if  $ab \equiv 1 \bmod p$?

I've tried using different ways from recurrence relations to many other ways, but I couldn't figure it out.
If someone could help, that would be a greatly appreciated.

P.S. I’ve edited the question apparently $a$ and $b$ are vertices too, it was an final exam question. Sorry for the mistake but it was hard to remember the whole question.

Comment: compute the degree of each node

Comment: What does it mean for vertice to correspond to $Z_p$? Are you talking about the label?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Working it out for small primes should be easy enough.  In general, though, for a fixed vertex $a\not \equiv 0 \pmod p$...how many other vertices is it connected to?  How many vertices is $0$ connected to?

Comment: Is the graph directed or undirected?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the set of integers with only prime numbers, and also from where I took the question it wasn’t specified that it was directed or undirected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

The vertices are $0,1,2, ..., p-1$, although $0$ is not connected to any other vertex.

Which vertex is connected to $1$? Which vertex is connected to $p-1$? What about any other vertex?

Assuming that vertices are not connected to themselves, consider the cases of $p=5$ and $p=7$.

In $\mathbb{Z}_5$, the following products are equal to $1$:-
$$1\times 1,2\times 3,4\times 4$$ Therefore the only edge is between $2$ and $3$.

In $\mathbb{Z}_7$, the following products are equal to $1$:-
$$1\times 1,2\times 4,3\times 5,6\times 6$$ Therefore the only edges are between $2$ and $4$ and between $3$ and $5$.

Can you generalise?

Comment: It really wasn’t specified from where I got it, that if a vertex can be connected to itself or that $p$ is odd or even.

Comment: Let's assume that $p$ is odd and vertices are not connected to themselves. I've now done $p=5$ in the above hint.

Comment: If you don’t mind, could you do a more in-depth explanation since I don’t quite get it why there are edges only between 2 and 3?

Comment: Yes, I've added this.

Comment: I get it now, since in modular arithmetic $ 2 \times 3$ is equal to 1 (of course considering $\mathbb{Z}_5$) and also taking in mind that $a$ and $b$ are connected to one edge. Thank you for solving it!